# disable accessing cdrom for specific user

Tags: 14.04, media

My question is how do I prevent a specific user from accessing cdrom?
I removed this user from cdrom group in `/etc/groups` but it still can access cdrom!
(am using ubuntu 14.04)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use the file system permissions to block all removable devices.

Currently in Ubuntu all removable devices are mounted in /media

Using the chmod command you can block all renovable devices:

```
sudo chmod 700 /media
```

This can be allow the root user only mount the removable disks not the normal users.

In order for the optical drive to be used only by root, you can also edit the file /etc/fstab:

```
exec sudo -i
mkdir /media/dvd
nano /etc/fstab
```

And add this line:

```
/dev/sr0    /media/dvd    auto    noauto,defaults    0 0
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Comment: These 2 methods give the permission only to the root user to use, but in  my case I have many normal users and I want to prevent one of them from accessing not the all..

Comment: Only one user : 'sudo chmod 700 /media/user'

Comment: I got it, but it is not a secure solution..Is there any way to prevent this user from mounting /dev/sr0?      Thanks @kyodake